# Java System.out under Unix with PuTTY is translating Tabs to 8 spaces

Tags: java, unix, putty

I have a Java Program which is writing Tabs to System.out.

This works fine under Windows.

Under Unix, connecting with PuTTY, the Tabs are being output as 8 spaces.
Correction: output is Tabbing to fixed Columns: 9, 17, 25, 33 & so on...

Does anyone have an idea which component might be doing that?
And how I can turn off that translation?

Addendum:
I too am fairly sure the culprit is not Java, but it's mentioned just to give the complete picture.

I strongly suspect it's PuTTY, but endless Googling could not shed any light on the matter.

Running locally on a Cinnamon Mint Linux (Ubuntu), the problem does not occur.

I did find this however:
[How UNIX Handles TAB Characters](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch41_04.htm)

Comment: How are you printing tabs? Show us the code.

Comment: I'd say it's a putty/shell setting anyway.

Comment: That sounds like an extraordinary claim. And, therefore, requires extraordinary evidence. It's far more likely you're e.g. trying to copy/paste by 'selecting the spaces' and the terminal emulator works like this. Java's `System.out` has absolutely no way of turning a tab character into 8 spaces.

Comment: System.out.println("colA" +"\t" + "colB"); is the code. As I mentioned, under Windows I can copy it to the clipboard & for example insert into Excel & it separates to 2 cols just fine. On a PuTTY Unix Session, I can select from 1 to 8 chars for each Tab & it inserts into Excel as 1 column.

Comment: It's a known low-priority bug in PuTTY: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/paste-fidelity.html